# Keep order while using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

Please advise how can I keep order while using multiprocessing in Python. Both func and somefunc return lists. Thanks,

```
results = []

def callback(*args): results.append(*args)

def in_parallel(fn, func):
   print 'Process started on',time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
   pool = mp.Pool(processes = 4)
   for num, i in enumerate(somefunc(fn)):
      pool.apply_async(func, args = (i,), callback = callback([num, callback]))
   pool.close()
   pool.join()

   return results
```

Comment: When you say "keep order" are you wanting to keep the ordering of `results` based on the time that the computation was done or something else?

Comment: no, I would like to keep the order of input list returned by somefunc

Comment: What do you actually want the `callback` kwarg to do? Right now you're just appending `num` followed by the `callback` function object to `results` as soon as you call `apply_async`, and then assigning the `callback` keyword argument to the return value of the `result.append` call, which is `None`. That's definitely not actually what you wanted to do.

Comment: I can easily sort resulting list in thr end. I simply don't know where to join num.

Comment: @user1192422 Can you add a sample input list and the expected output to your example? I'm still not sure what you actually want the output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved with the following:

```
  r = pool.map_async(...)
  r.wait()
```

Comment: But `r.wait` makes it much slower in my case